# How to use NgRx in a composable way (without circular code dependencies on AppState, but still typesafe)?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

## Problem

When applying NgRx to my Angular project, I want to avoid that any NgRx selectors or Angular components
depend on a global `AppState` type (that would be the effective generic type `T` of NgRx's `Store<T>`)
(because allowing that would lead to a circular dependency in the source code, somewhere between
the respective component and Angular's `app.module.ts`).

I struggle to achive that without compromising the TypeScript typechecker or the ESLint checker.

I am currently using NgRx 15 (with Angular 15) and the ESLint `@ngrx/all-requiring-type-checking` plugin.

## Dissatisfying Workaround

I have a work-around, with some shortcommings.

This is derived from the current [NgRx tutorial](https://ngrx.io/guide/store#tutorial),
with following three code snippets:

- `my-counter.ngrx.ts` defines the component' state and the NgRx action(s),
  reducer(s) and selector(s):

```
import { createAction, createReducer, createSelector, on } from '@ngrx/store';

// component's state

export interface MyCounterState { count: number }

// action(s)

export const increment = createAction('[Counter Component] Increment');
export const decrement = createAction('[Counter Component] Decrement');

// reducer(s)

export const counterReducer = createReducer(
  <MyCounterState>{ count: 0},
  on(increment, (state: MyCounterState): MyCounterState => <MyCounterState>{...state, count: state.count + 1}),
  on(decrement, (state: MyCounterState): MyCounterState => <MyCounterState>{...state, count: state.count - 1}),
);

// selector(s)

const selectMyCounterState = (state: {myCounterState: MyCounterState}) => state.myCounterState;
const projectCount = (state: MyCounterState): number => state.count;

export const selectCount = createSelector(selectMyCounterState, projectCount);
```

- `app.module.ts` configures NgRx for the Angular application:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot({ myCounterState: counterReducer }, {}),
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

- `my-counter.component.ts` uses the NgRx store:

```
@Component(...)
export class MyCounterComponent {

  count$: Observable<number>;

  constructor(private store: Store<{ myCounterState: MyCounterState }>) {
    this.count$ = store.select(selectCount);
  }

  readonly increment = () => this.store.dispatch(increment());
  readonly decrement = () => this.store.dispatch(decrement());
}
```

## Open Problems

The workaround can be polished further, e.g. by declaring and using an
interface instead of `{ myCounterState: MyCounterState }` and a constant
instead of `{ myCounterState: counterReducer }`, but some problems remain:

- the identifiers `myCounterState` in `{ myCounterState: MyCounterState }`
  (required for Selectors or other places accessing the Store) and `myCounterState`
  in `{ myCounterState: counterReducer }` have to match magically; the TypeScript typechecker cannot guarantee that at compile time (and likewise, refactoring tools cannot consistently rename them)

  - this seems to be a general problem of the NgRx API (because `StoreModule.forRoot(...)`
    is configured by NgRx Reducers, and the type of the NgRx Store is derived implicitly
    from the Reducer's type signatures)
- the ESLint plugin `@ngrx/all-requiring-type-checking` still complains about the generic
  parameter in `constructor(private store: Store<{ myCounterState: MyCounterState }>)` (in the component's code snippet above)
  and wants to see a raw `constructor(private store: Store)` instead

  - which I find a strange demand from the ESLint plugin, because `Store` *is* a
    generic type, and providing the type parameter is essential for the TypeScript
    typechecker to check the Selector implementations and usages at compile time

## Actual Questions

As shown above, I struggle to apply NgRx in a way that is composable *and* typesafe *and* accepted by NgRx ESLint plugin
(again, composable meaning that components and selectors should be independent of any global `AppState` type, the generic
type parameter of `Store<T>`).

- Is there a concise and clean pattern for that?
- Or is it simply impossible with the current NgRx 15 API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, it's hard to type this correctly because the state in the store is "constantly" changing at run-time.

I think what you're missing in the snippets is a feature selector. In my opinion, using this makes interacting with the store simpler.

```
// instead of this
const selectMyCounterState = (state: {myCounterState: MyCounterState}) => state.myCounterState;

// do this
const selectMyCounterState = createFeatureSelector<MyCounterState>(myCounterStateKey);
```

While we can still make a mistake with this, it's a good base.

Because the selector to select the feature is now typed, you can use it further to create child selectors.
And you can also drop the generic from the `Store`. The selector will handle all of that.

Also, some newer features like `createFeature` help to keep things consistent and typed. You can also do `Store.forFeature(myFeature)`, this way you don't need to share the interface in the module.
For example, a feature comes with the base selectors to retrieve the  state.

Side note, you don't need to cast the reducer as this can lead to problems.

```
// don't do this
 on(increment, (state: MyCounterState): MyCounterState => <MyCounterState>{...state, count: state.count + 1}),
// instead do

 on(increment, (state: MyCounterState): MyCounterState => ({...state, count: state.count + 1})),
```

Some links that might be useful:

- https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/you-should-take-advantage-of-the-improved-ngrx-apis
- https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/stop-misusing-typescript-type-assertions

Comment: Works, thanks for the quick help!

Comment: ...and also thanks for the 'stop misusing typescript type assertions' advice; I am just learning, and this was spot-on on something I had misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

## 'Improved Workaround' Snippets

Thanks to @timdeschryver's answer, I can get rid of the ESLint warning and can get away with exporting less implementation details from `my-counter.ngrx.ts`. This solves most of the problems I had.

Still unresolved is the necessity for the magic match of the Reducer key (object field name) and the FeatureSelector key (string value), but at least these can be non-public implementation details that can be kept close together in one source file.

**For sake of completness**, this is the pattern I am now working with, based on the [NgRx tutorial](https://ngrx.io/guide/store#tutorial), with following three code snippets:

- `my-counter.ngrx.ts` defines the component' state and the NgRx action(s),
  reducer(s) and selector(s):

```
import { createAction, createFeatureSelector, createReducer, createSelector, on } from '@ngrx/store';

// component's state

interface MyCounterState { count: number }

// action(s)

export const increment = createAction('[Counter Component] Increment');
export const decrement = createAction('[Counter Component] Decrement');

// reducer(s)

const counterReducer = createReducer(
  { count: 0},
  on(increment, (state: MyCounterState): MyCounterState => ({...state, count: state.count + 1})),
  on(decrement, (state: MyCounterState): MyCounterState => ({...state, count: state.count - 1})),
);

export const MY_COUNTER_APP_REDUCERS = { myCounterState: counterReducer };

// selector(s)

const selectMyCounterState = createFeatureSelector<MyCounterState>('myCounterState');
const projectCount = (state: MyCounterState): number => state.count;

export const selectCount = createSelector(selectMyCounterState, projectCount);
```

- `app.module.ts` configures NgRx for the Angular application:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot({
      ...MY_COUNTER_APP_REDUCERS,
      // ...and more
    }),
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

- `my-counter.component.ts` uses the NgRx store:

```
@Component(...)
export class MyCounterComponent {

  count$: Observable<number>;

  constructor(private store: Store) {
    this.count$ = store.select(selectCount);
  }

  readonly increment = () => this.store.dispatch(increment());
  readonly decrement = () => this.store.dispatch(decrement());
}
```